# Film or series where bacteria were the protagonists

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I think this film/show was made in the early 2000s.

It featured some sort of bacterial habitats co-existing in a boy's body. The good bacteria would fight off the bad ones, and when they failed, the boy would suffer repercussions, like having a fever or blacking out, etc.

Any idea what this film or show's name is?

Comment: Was this live action, animated, or a combination of the two? Where were you when you watched it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suspect that this is the animated series *Ozzy & Drix*, which aired between 2002 and 2004.

[image]

A spin-off of the live-action/animated hybrid film *Osmosis Jones*, *Ozzy & Drix* features Osmosis Jones, a white blood cell, and Drix, an over-the-counter cold-relief pill, as they battle germs, diseases, and other illnesses, inside the body of teenager Hector Cruz.

You may be remembering *Osmosis Jones* itself, but in the film, they were inside the body of a middle-aged man played (in live-action) by Bill Murray, rather than a teenage boy as you remember, so I think *Ozzy & Drix* is more likely.

Comment: Right on point, was looking for this, Cheers!

Comment: I actually remembered this show a few months ago. I was quickly able to find it by searching _"animated series with bacteria in human body"_ (but only on Google, which isn't my main search engine; it became quite good at identifying stuffs from a context)

Answer (score 16):

There is another series that aired slightly earlier (~1988) that fits the description: [Once Upon a time: Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time..._Life)

It features the different parts of the body, how they work together, how they recognize and battle germs, diseases, cuts and other things.

Most of the series is from the inside of the body, but there are outside views that show the effect of the illness or how they happened in the first place.

[image]